# laravel 9 css not display properly

Tags: css, laravel, vite

I have create a new laravel 9 project and I have encounter an css and js assets connection  problem

At first, I have run

```
php artisan serve
```

to see if my project is working , and seems like everything is fine .
[image]

but when I just simply remove an part from the view , the css/js just get disabled to the view
[image]

even I undo the changes , the css are still not working . did any know whats happen?

here is my code for the css, and I believe it was properly connected

```
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Admin Dashboard  </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta content="Premium Multipurpose Admin & Dashboard Template" name="description" />
        <meta content="Themesdesign" name="author" />
        <!-- App favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('backend/assets/images/favicon.ico')}}">

        <!-- jquery.vectormap css -->
        <link href="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- DataTables -->
        <link href="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- Responsive datatable examples -->
        <link href="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  

        <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
        <link href="{{ asset('backend/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Icons Css -->
        <link href="{{ asset('backend/assets/css/icons.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- App Css-->
        <link href="{{ asset('backend/assets/css/app.min.css')}}" id="app-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>
```

```
codes for vite.config.js

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
            'resources/css/app.css',
             'resources/js/app.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

I have already do some research and seems like it might be related to the "vite", but It was something very strange to me . Could anyone tell me what should I do . Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you get a warning in your console?

Comment: no , i didnt get any warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From version 9.19.0 Laravel has drop the webpack and added the vitejs

To add css and js, you need to configure the vite

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'backend/assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css',
            'backend/assets/libs/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css',
            'backend/assets/libs/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css',
            'backend/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            'backend/assets/css/icons.min.css',
            'backend/assets/css/app.min.css',
        ]),
    ],
});
```

To run the dev serve `npm run dev`

In blade

```
@vite([
    'backend/assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css',
    'backend/assets/libs/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css',
    'backend/assets/libs/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css',
    'backend/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'backend/assets/css/icons.min.css',
    'backend/assets/css/app.min.css',
]);
```

For more information [laravel vite doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite)